# Laravel: How do I validate a date ONLY if the date exists?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a form, it has a date field called `starts`, which is optional:

```
...
<input type="date" name="starts">
...
```

Then I created a Request in Laravel that checks, among other things, if `starts` is a date, so the `rules()` function in the Request is somthing like:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    ... (more validation rules)
    'starts'             => 'date',
    ... (more validation rules)
  ];
}
```

So, when I submit the form and there's no `starts`, the validation rules kicks in, it says it's not a date, and returns to my form.

How do I tell Laravel that `starts` is a date, only if it is present?

I'm looking something like the validation in files, which only take place if there's a file present

Comment: try required_if. for more detail https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: You can use `sometimes` [rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add "nullable" for your laravel validation rule like so:

```
'starts' => 'date|nullable'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find it in the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-date

Comment: I'm hoping that you are using 5.7 and not 5.0, it's on version 5.7 documentation, click here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Comment: nullable|date is the correct one

Comment: doesn't matter, it works the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try `'starts' => 'nullable|date'` as validation rule. There is a section about this in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).